# HTML editor removes FreeMarker tags inside <table> tag

Tags: html, freemarker

I use FreeMarker to build various templates from email to invoice templates. Issue that i am seeking right now is related to FreeMarker code being extracted outside table tag since HTML doesn't allow other characters inside it beside tbody, thead, tr.

Would be glad if anyone has an idea how to bypass this.

Example:

```
<table>
                    <tbody>
                        [#assign eventDetails = []]
                        [#if items?? && items?has_content]
                            [#list items as item]
                                <tr>
                                    <td  style="padding: 5px;vertical-align: top;border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; text-align: center;">
                                        ${item.name}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            [/#list]
                        [/#if]
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

become like this after being applied to editor using element.innerHTML:

```
[#assign eventDetails = []]
[#if items?? && items?has_content]
  [#list items as item]
  [/#list]
[/#if]
<table>
                    <tbody>
 
                                <tr>
                                    <td  style="padding: 5px;vertical-align: top;border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; text-align: center;">
                                        ${item.name}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately you're going to have to either modify the code of the HTML editor or find another solution for how you're editing them before they are rendered.

Comment: Argh, that is what i was afraid of. I already did modification and use div with flex to get table like look and it works fine in browser but over email and PDF that doesn't work. Thanks for your proposal though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It of course only depends on the HTML editor you are using, but you should try if same happens if, either:

- You are using the `<#...>` syntax instead. That looks like some unknown tag for the editor, not CDATA, so maybe it doesn't react the same way.
- Replace `<tbody>...</tbody>` with `[@html.tbody]...[/@html.tbody]`. Then the editor  might won't be confident enough to remove stuff. Or, the same with `[@html.table]`, etc. Quite awkward, but might be better than what you have now. (For that to actually work when running the template, you will have to define the `tbody` macro in the `html` namespace of course. It's not built in.)

Example of the last:

```
<#ftl output_format='HTML'>

<#macro table attrs...><@elementWithNested 'table' attrs><#nested></@></#macro>
<#macro tbody attrs...><@elementWithNested 'tbody' attrs><#nested></@></#macro>

<#macro elementWithNested elementName attrs>
<${elementName}<#if attrs?size != 0><#list attrs as k, v> ${k}="${v}"</#list></#if>>
<#nested>  
</${elementName}>
</#macro>
```

If above template is `#import`-ed as `html`, then `<@html.table foo="bar">...</@html.table>` etc. will work.

Comment: Bless you! You saved a week of pain for me with your suggestion. :) I have solved this using macros and now it works like a charm. Problem lays within innerHTML function using DOM and most of editors use that to render HTML properly inside textarea.